# Bootstrap not loaded correctly?

Tags: javascript, css, ruby-on-rails, sass

I just made a Ruby project on which I wanted to add bootstrap.
I use WebPacker to load CSS and JS files.

Here is my application.html.erb layout:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang=fr>
 <head>
  <title>Blog</title>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
  <%= csp_meta_tag %>

  <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
  <%= stylesheet_pack_tag 'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
  <%= javascript_pack_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>

 </head>
 <body>
   <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
    <div class="container-fluid">
     <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">WebSiteName</a>
     </div>
     <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Page 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
     </ul>
     <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
      <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Sign Up</a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Login</a></li>
     </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>


  <div class="container">
   <%= yield %>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Here is the result :

[image]

Problem is on the navbar naturally, it should be well formatted and in a black color.
Here is my application.js supposed to load my site.scss (css) and my site.js (js) on /app/javascript/packs :

```
require("@rails/ujs").start()
//require("turbolinks").start()
require("@rails/activestorage").start()
require("channels")

import "bootstrap";

//CSS
import "../scss/site"

// JS
import "../js/site"
console.log("imported js")

document.addEventListener("turbolinks:load", () => {
$('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip()
$('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover()
})
```

Here is my site.scss file in /app/javascript/scss :

```
@import "~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss";
```

Here is network loading files results:

[image]

Comment: 304 is not an error code, it means the file hasn't changed

Comment: Ok, it was also to point that the js webpack file was well loaded

Answer (score 1):

In your `application.css` or `site.scss` you may need to add:

```
@import 'bootstrap/scss/bootstrap';
```

Comment: I already have 
    `@import "~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss";`
not good ?

Comment: don't work, i already have the import for bootstrap in my 
site.scss

Comment: You have your site.scss file in /app/javascript/scss, maybe move it to: /ass/assets/stylesheets?

Comment: I added `@import 'bootstrap'` in site.scss, seems it works quite well, thanks!